# Where is the ADB server code that handles the "devices" command?

Tags: adb, android-source

I'm reading the source code of ADB, which comes from AOSP. I traced the flow of receiving the command `adb devices`. I found that the client sends this command to the server and then reads the answer from the server. But where is the logic of the server that handles this message? I can't find it. Can you point it out for me? The source can be found [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/tree/master/adb). I'm referring to the Linux version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, it's in `adb.cpp`, following [this line](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/9f5e6dbe854ca41d337a1fa8fc8efe95e22db04b/adb/adb.cpp#L1094).